# Using Parceler with android

Tags: android, parceler

I'm trying [Parceler](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler) library for android. So far I've had only one same error, using plain sample from the documentation.

```
@Parcel(Parcel.Serialization.BEAN)
public class Example {
  private String name;
  private int age;

  public String getName() { return name; }
  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

  public int getAge() { return age; }
  public void setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }
}
```

And

```
Parcelable p = Parcels.wrap(new Example());
```

Which crashes with

```
07-30 12:31:46.439: E/AndroidRuntime(4945): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 12:31:46.439: E/AndroidRuntime(4945): Process: com.sample.app.android.debug, PID: 4945
07-30 12:31:46.439: E/AndroidRuntime(4945):  org.parceler.ParcelerRuntimeException: Unable to find generated Parcelable  class for com.sample.app.android.entity.Example, verify that  your class is configured properly and that the Parcelable class  com.sample.app.android.entity.Example$$Parcelable is generated  by Parceler.
07-30 12:31:46.439: E/AndroidRuntime(4945):     at  org.parceler.Parcels$ParcelCodeRepository.get(Parcels.java:201)
07-30 12:31:46.439: E/AndroidRuntime(4945):     at org.parceler.Parcels.wrap(Parcels.java:85)
07-30 12:31:46.439: E/AndroidRuntime(4945):     at org.parceler.Parcels.wrap(Parcels.java:69)
```

What do I miss?

Comment: Where do you actually set using the setter method?

Comment: @Raghunandan I found the problem, actually. Installation was incomplete, although it was not clear. Will post the answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the annotation processor isn't running or is misconfigured.  I'd recommend using the annotationProcessor scope if you're using a Gradle build along with separate scopes for the processor and api libraries:

```
compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.9'
annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.9'
```

See the [Getting Parceler](http://parceler.org#getting_parceler) section of the website for the latest.

Answer (score 2):

In the newer version, you only have to update the following dependencies in your Gradle file:

```
compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.6'
annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.6'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of annotation. it works by implementing in build.gradle

```
annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.9'
```